# How to pass a user-defined record from a procedure back to the calling program in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

The package below will insert 10 records into a table, then I need to pass those records back to the calling program and display them. I've tried different things that I could think of and the many searches over the internet, haven't been successful in finding what I'm trying to do.

PACKAGE SPECIFICATION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Hospital AS 

  TYPE TrtRecTyp IS RECORD (
      Pat_Nbr Treatment.Pat_Nbr%TYPE, 
      Trt_Procedure Treatment.Trt_Procedure%TYPE,
      Phys_ID Physician.Phys_ID%TYPE,
      Phys_Name Physician.Phys_Name%TYPE,
      Phys_Specialty Physician.Phys_Specialty%TYPE);          

 PROCEDURE BuildPatTbl                                                 
  (p_trt_rec OUT TrtRecTyp,
   p_num_rows IN OUT NUMBER);
```

PACKAGE BODY:

```
PROCEDURE BuildPatTbl                                                 
  (p_trt_rec OUT TrtRecTyp,
   p_num_rows IN OUT NUMBER) AS   

    CURSOR pat_cur  IS    
    SELECT trt.Pat_Nbr, Trt_Procedure, trt.Phys_ID, Phys_Name, Phys_Specialty   
    FROM Treatment trt, Physician phys 
    WHERE trt.Phys_ID = phys.Phys_ID;    

    lv_rec_cnt_num NUMBER(2);

BEGIN
      lv_rec_cnt_num := p_num_rows;
      FOR lv_trt_rec IN pat_cur  LOOP  
         INSERT INTO t_patTrt (T_patTrt_ID, Pat_Nbr, Trt_Procedure, 
                 Phys_ID, Phys_Name,  Phys_Specialty)  
         VALUES(T_patTrt_ID_seq.NEXTVAL, lv_trt_rec.Pat_Nbr,
                 lv_trt_rec.Trt_Procedure, lv_trt_rec.Phys_ID, 
                 lv_trt_rec.Phys_Name, lv_trt_rec.Phys_Specialty);

           lv_rec_cnt_num := lv_rec_cnt_num + 1 ;         

      END LOOP;     

      p_num_rows := lv_rec_cnt_num;

END BuildPatTbl;
```

CALLING PROGRAM:

```
DECLARE
treat_rec Hospital.TrtRecTyp;
lv_cnt_num NUMBER(2) := 0;
lv_row_cnt_num NUMBER(2);

BEGIN    

   i Hospital.BuildPatTbl(treat_rec, lv_cnt_num);     

    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP

           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Pat_Nbr = ' || treat_rec.Pat_Nbr);
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Trt_Procedure = ' || treat_rec.Trt_Procedure);
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Phys_ID = ' || treat_rec.Phys_ID);
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Phys_Name = ' || treat_rec.Phys_Name);
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Phys_Specialty = ' || treat_rec.Phys_Specialty);   

    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The number of rows returned in the table is: ' || lv_cnt_num);

END;
```

Comment: read up about pl/sql collections.

Comment: I've read quite a bit about pl/sql collections, but I haven't found anything that addresses my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you getting?

It looks like you're not selecting any data into your `p_trt_rec` variable for starters, so you won't return anything in your procedure.

You should be saving each row into a collection (which you're not doing currently) and pass the entire collection back from `BuildPatTbl`, then iterate through it.

You need another variable and type declaration. It will be something like-

`TYPE my_tbl IS TABLE OF TrtRecTyp;
   my_list my_tbl;`

Then store each record in `my_list` and return it.

Check out [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_collections.htm) for more guidance.

Comment: I'm not getting an error. The last record is the only one that's getting returned. The lv_trt_rec is suppose to be p_trt_rec. If I do it the way you suggest than the p_trt_rec OUT parameter wouldn't be getting returned or am I missing something?